# Message time displayed similar for all receive messages

Tags: java, android

Chat output is looking like this when one send message and receive message(Right side is send message to others & left side is receive message from others).
[image]

when i am receive second message from others the time of previous receive message changed as current receive message time.In my first chat window the receive message time is"11:02 pm" but, In my second image the previous receive message time is changed as current time (i.e)"11:05pm".how to fix this issue please help me.

[image]

My programming code is below

```
   if (messagesItems.get(position).isSelf() == 1) {
                        // message belongs to you, so load the right aligned layout
                        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.chat_message_right,
                                null);
                        //TextView lblFrom = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblMsgFrom);
                        TextView txtMsg = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtMsg);
                        //date and time declared on date here
                        TextView date = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtInfo);
                        try {
                            //actualDate contains date "(i.e)27-Aug-2015 6:20:25 am/pm" in this format
                            String actualDate = m.getDate();
                            Date FormatDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy h:mm:ss a").parse(actualDate);
                            //actualDate converted from "(i.e)27-Aug-2015 6:20:25 am/pm" to "6:20 pm" in this
                            //format for display the chat time for every chat message .
                            dateResult = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm a").format(FormatDate);

                            // lblFrom.setText(m.getFromName());
                        } catch (ParseException e) {

                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        date.setText(dateResult);
                        txtMsg.setText(m.getMessage());

                    } else{
                        // message belongs to other person, load the left aligned layout

                        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.chat_message_left,
                                null);

                        TextView txtMsg = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtMsg);
                        TextView date = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtInfo);
                        String actualDate = m.getDate();           

                       if(actualDate==null)
                       {
                        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm a");
                        String strDate = sdf.format(c.getTime());
                        date.setText(strDate);
                       }
                        txtMsg.setText(m.getMessage());

}

        }

        return convertView;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `else` block doesn't seem to be using `m.getDate()`. Follow the same procedure than in the `if` block, i.e. 
(assuming `m = messageItems.get(position)`)

```
String actualDate = m.getDate();
Date FormatDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy h:mm:ss a").parse(actualDate);
dateResult = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm a").format(FormatDate);
```

Comment: when i am using the same if condition procedure in else condition i am getting null pointer exception..

Comment: which variable is null in this case ?

Comment: String actualDate give null response

Comment: Well then you should find out why the messages you receive don't have a date. If you want to set a date on the fly it's probably fine, but you need to keep it for each message. e.g.
    if (m.getDate() == null) {
        m.setDate(Calendar.getInstance());
    }
    String actualDate = m.getDate();

Comment: i am getting error on "m.setDate(Calendar.getInstance()); } ".the error is "setDate(java.lang.String) in chatMessageObjects  cannot be applied to(java.util.Calender)" which code now i am edit..

Comment: can you please check my else condition code now time should displayed on receive messages.But when new message is coming all previous receive message time changed as current time (like as i am mentioned my second image).how to solve that issue

Comment: That was an example, you should pass whatever is needed in `setDate()` set to the current time. The important thing here is that you do it only once when you receive the message.

Comment: can you please check my else condition code for get the receive message time, the time displayed on chat message successfully but when new receive message coming all previous chat timings are changed..

Comment: you're still not doing m.setDate(...) in the else { if() } block